# Reverse number logic is not working using javascript

Tags: javascript

I got a question from on line and I tried to solve it,please check the question below,

`Reverse Number
Given a number N, print reverse of number N.
Note: Do not print leading zeros in output.
For example N = 100
Reverse of N will be 1 not 001.
Input: Input contains a single integer N.
Output: Print reverse of integer N.
Constraints:
1<=N<=10000`

I tried to solve this using my below logic but I stuck in some place,I don't know what's wrong with my code,please check this

```
function rvrs() {
            var a, no, b,temp = 0;
            no = Number(document.getElementById("no_input").value);

            b = no;
            while (no > 0)
            {
                a = no % 10;
                temp = temp * 10 + a;
            }
            document.getElementById("txt1").value = a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question I have solved already, your logic is correct but where are you parsing the integer and dividing? and also the output value you're taking from wrong variable,it should be `temp` not `a`.

Check my solution,

```
function rvrs() {
        var a, no, b,temp = 0;
        no = Number(document.getElementById("no_input").value);

        b = no;
        while (no > 0)
        {
            a = no % 10;
            no = parseInt(no / 10);
            temp = temp * 10 + a;
        }
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some array functions:

```
var test = 123456
var reversed = parseInt(test.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))
```